# Global robots tag is not inserted, only when you do it on menu basis or article basis

Tags: joomla-3.x

When I set the index,follow in the global configuration and set everything regarding this robots tag to use global it will not actually render the robots tag. It just does not render it at all.

Only when I set it to index,follow in my menu item or article it will render the tag. How can I change this? I want it to always render the tag, when its index,follow but also when it's configured to use global.

Comment: robots index and follow is the default value hence the tag is redundant.  Is there a reason you want it explicitly?